# AngularJS ui-router behavior

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I'm using angularJS with ui-router to manage my routes. I use the same controller(that has functions to manage my users like add, edit and delete) for some different states or routes as the following:

```
                  .state('manage', {
                        abstract: true,
                        url: '/manage',
                        views: {
                            '': {
                              templateUrl: 'views/layout.html'
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .state('state1', {
                        url: '/list-users',
                        controller: 'ManageCtrl',
                        templateUrl: 'views/pages/manage/list-users.html',
                    })
                    .state('state2', {
                        url: '/add-user',
                        controller: 'ManageCtrl',
                        templateUrl: 'views/pages/manage/add-user.html',
                    })
```

First, Is this is correct? what is the best practice to do something like my case?

Second, What is the behavior of ui-router, Are it each time state changed, it reinitializes the controller? because i'm using `$caheFactory` in my controller as the following:

```
$scope.cache = $cacheFactory('manageUsers');
```

When the state changed, an error `CacheId 'manageUsers' is already taken!`
occurred.

Comment: $cacheFactory should be used as a service.  Are you trying to set it up inside your controller?

Comment: i use it as a service and inject it in my controller `app.controller('ManageCtrl', ['$cacheFactory' , function($cacheFactory){ //some logic here}]);`

Answer (score 0):

for your case you can use multiview child contents like below

```
.state("organizationSetup.system", {
    url: "/system",
    views: {
      "contents": {
        templateUrl: "system.html",
        controller: "systemCtrl"
      }
    },
    permission: "readRole",
    context: {
      product: "Admin"
    },
    title: "System"
  }).state("organizationSetup.system.new", {
    url: "/new",
    permission: "system",
    context: {
      product: "Admin"
    },
    views: {
      "childContents": {
        templateUrl: "system.new.html"
      }
    },
    title: "System New"
  }).state("organizationSetup.system.view", {
    url: "/view",
    permission: "system",
    context: {
      product: "Admin"
    },
    views: {
      "childContents": {
        templateUrl: "system.view.html"
      }
    }
```

in this case controller and services will not be initialized again. in your case your controller, services will be initialized for each state.